# linq group data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

raw data:

```
StrDateTime ServerName 
9/15/2012 3:01:19 PM 'srvr1'
9/15/2012 3:01:19 PM 'srvr2'
9/15/2012 3:01:19 PM 'srvr33'
9/15/2012 3:02:15 PM 'srvr1'
9/15/2012 3:02:15 PM 'srvr5'
```

my code(`not work`):

```
(from data in dataInToday
group data by data.StrDateTime into grp
let srvrs = (from i in grp select i.ServerName).ToString()
select new
{ 
    grp.Key,
    srvrs
}).Take(20).Dump();
```

expected output:

```
Key srvrs 
9/15/2012 3:01:19 PM 'srvr1, srvr2, srvr33'
9/15/2012 3:02:15 PM 'srvr1, srvr5'
9/15/2012 3:02:43 PM 'srvr1, srvr2'
9/15/2012 3:03:19 PM 'srvr9, srvr2'
9/15/2012 3:04:19 PM 'srvr5, srvr11'
9/15/2012 3:05:19 PM 'srvr1, srvr2'
```

is there a linq function can implement it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
(from data in dataInToday
group data by data.StrDateTime into grp
let srvrs = string.Join(", ", (from i in grp select i.ServerName))
select new
    { 
       grp.Key,
       srvrs
    }).Take(20).Dump();
```